# Convert highcharts xaxis etremes to yaxis extremes

Tags: highcharts

I have two highcharts on my page. A bar graph and a column graph. The column graph xaxis has 50 categories. The bar graph yaxis also has 50 categories. When i zoom in on the column graph the yaxis of the bar graph does not zoom the same way.

I figured out that it had to do with the value zooming gives. So is there a way to convert the xaxis extremes tot yaxis extremes so that my zoomin wil be the same on both graphs?

This is how i set the extremes:

```
events: {
                selection: function (event) {
                    var xMin;
                    var yMin;
                    var xMax;
                    var yMax;
                    if (event.xAxis) {
                        xMin = event.xAxis[0].min;
                        xMax = event.xAxis[0].max;
                        yMin = xMin;
                        yMax = xMax;
                        if (incomeChart != undefined)
                            incomeChart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax, true);
                        if (timeLine != undefined)
                            timeLine.yAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin, xMax, true);
```

Comment: Are you calling setExtremes on the bar graph manually ?

Comment: is put the code in my post abopve

Comment: Could you recreate issue on jsFiddle? I think, the reason may be that `minRange` for categories is 1, while actual extremes from seletion can vary for example 1.234 to 12.67. So you can try to add `Math.round(xMin);` etc. to make sure proper extremes are set.

Comment: I tried the Math.round() it got me closer but not there yet. I have a jsfiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bp2Za/) if you zoomin on first 3 year on the top graph its shows more then 3 years in the bottom graph